# Goutte does not submit a form

Tags: symfony, testing, behat, mink, goutte

Searching test on homepage works ok. 
But I'm not sure how submit should work and how to debug it. That's what I have:

**behat.yml**

```
default:
    formatter:
        name: progress
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension\Extension:
            mink_driver: true
            kernel:
                env:   test
                debug: true
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            base_url:        http://my.dev/
            goutte: ~
```

**Search.feature**

```
Feature: Search
    Search

    Background:
        Given I am on "/"

    Scenario: Empty Search
        When I fill in "query" with "love"
        And I press "Search"
        Then I should see "Love Results"
```

**bash**

```
$ ./bin/behat --verbose --profile=default "@MySiteBundle/Search.feature"
...F.P-..P-..P--.F---.F---

(::) failed steps (::)

01. The text "Love Results" was not found anywhere in the text of the current page.                
+--[ HTTP/1.1 200 | http://my.dev/ | GoutteDriver ]
```

So address is still "/" which means that form was not submitted.

Is Goutte a wrong driver for this purpose? Or is it my strange config (because "/" is not served by symfony2, other part of site is)?

**UPDATE**:

Debug from inside of BroserKit/Client shows that URI where form is supposed to be submitted to is wrong, returns 404. And behat in verbose mode does not show that.

Answer (score 0):

If your form submit is handled by Javascript, you should use Selenuim2 instead of goutte, and add the @javascript annotation on top of your feature file.

Comment: It is a "classic" form. no js.